# AssertionError: Invalid CUDA '--device 0' requested, use '--device cpu' or pass valid CUDA device(s)

Tags: python, pytorch, yolov5

I have a docker container running on node hosted on aws eks. The container has yolov5 repo cloned. I want to train the model using gpu on my node which is g4 instance. I run the following command:

```
python3 train.py --device 0
```

but it gives the following error:

> File "/app/yolov5/utils/torch_utils.py", line 118, in select_device
> assert torch.cuda.is_available() and torch.cuda.device_count() >= len(device.replace(',', '')), 
> AssertionError: Invalid CUDA '--device 0' requested, use '--device cpu' or pass valid CUDA device(s)

i have tried nvidia-smi

> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
> | NVIDIA-SMI 470.161.03   Driver Version: 470.161.03   CUDA Version: N/A      |
> |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
> | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
> | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
> |                               |                      |               MIG M. |
> |===============================+======================+======================|
> |   0  Tesla T4            On   | 00000000:00:1E.0 Off |                    0 |
> | N/A   30C    P8     9W /  70W |      0MiB / 15109MiB |      0%      Default |
> |                               |                      |                  N/A |
> +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
I checked nvcc version too
All CUDA libraries and nvidia container toolkit is installed properly
pytorch version is 1.12.1 and CUDA version is 11.4
Cant figure out what the issue is!!